# pfsense: After restoring config boot stops at "TSC: P-state invariant"

Tags: boot, pfsense

I'm setting up a brand new pfsense and it works fine. Then I restore the configuration from another working installation and when I try to reboot it freezes soon after mouting the / partition and detecting the CPU. The last line in my screen is:

```
TSC: P-state invariant
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the configuration file with a text editor and if you see any of these lines remove it:

```
<enableserial></enableserial> 
# or
<primaryconsole>serial</primaryconsole>
```

Booting proceeds but all messages are send to the serial port instead of your screen.